# write console output to excel sheet using DataFrame python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

```
for foo in root.finadall(xpath):
       print (foo.name[xpath], foo.country[xpath])
       df = DataFrame({'Name': foo.name[xpath], 'conutry': foo.country[xpath]})
       df.to_excel('foo.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

The output prints the lots of names in the console. But In excel, It stores only the least one. How do i store all the names in the excel.

To get on clear idea:

```
The console output:
Name           Country 
jennfier       abc
andy john      cde
carwl          xyz
```

In excel i see the only carwl xyz.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your excel file in each iteration of the loop, so try to collect all your data first, then generate a single DataFrame based on collected data and save it as Excel

```
DataFrame({'Name': collected_data_list}).to_excel('foo.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

PS you should really provide a sample and desired data sets if you want to have neat answers...